# How to use Bing's search API?

Tags: oauth, get, bing

I am having a hard time understanding Oauth verification. I'm trying to use bing's search api. They request oauth verification. I have a primary key that they gave me. The issue I am running into it how to make a request, providing the oauth verification key.

For example, if I try to make a get request by the following:

```
http//api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search?Query=%27xbox%27
```

I receive an error

```
The authorization type you provided is not supported.  Only Basic and OAuth are supported
```

So the question is, do I embed my key into the URL, something like

```
http//api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search?Query=%27xbox%27&authetication="myautherizationkey"
```

How do I provide my credentials in order to access their api?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a complete answer, because I'm still getting a "401 Unauthorized" error, but here is how I configured my OAuth for AngularJS. This is for a Bing image search.

```
var accountKey = '/*Your Account Key*/';
    var base64EncodedKey = btoa(accountKey);
    $http({
      method: 'GET',  
      url: 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/v1/Image?Query=%27Pizza%27&$format=JSON',
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + base64EncodedKey}
    }).success(function(json) {
      console.log('Returned: ' + JSON.stringify(json)); 
    }).error(function(err) {
      console.log('There was an error retrieving the image JSON: ' + err); 
    });
```

This at least gets rid of the authorization *type* error, but I still seem to have an error with the way I am providing the account key. Hope it helps point you in the right direction!